# Registered users on my remote database can't be accesed, but it works locally, how come?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, passwords

I'm working on a school project where the goal is to create a database of users on a webpage. The current goal is to be able to register users, and login, which works when I run it locally on my computer. However, when I use the exact same code, but on a server (that we've rented), the password/account name returns faulty. I use the same code for both locally, and on the server, and yet it doesn't work.

Is there something that has to be done differently when I use it remotely, contrary to locally?

For clarification, the password is indeed hashed, and we've used proper statements for the task.

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting( E_ALL );

include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    global $mysqli;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pwdFromDB = '';

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pwd FROM Persons WHERE email = ? ")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($pwdFromDB);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    if(password_verify($password, $pwdFromDB)) {
        $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.alert('Du har loggat in!');
        window.location = 'book.html';
        </script>");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.alert('Fel användarnamn eller lösenord!');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>");
        exit();
    }


}



?>
```

Comment: what error message is displayed?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the password/account name returns faulty" ?  What _exactly_ is returned?

Comment: you're using database, are you sure that your local database has the same data as rented server? also - you're not checking for errors, try to display them at least mysqil->error

Comment: The error message is that the account name/password is wrong. But even if I add the exact same data into my local database, as the remote one, the local version works, but the remote one does not.

The register function works, but the login does not.

Comment: If it's telling you the account name/password is wrong, is it **your** error message (the one in your alert()) ?  If so, then var_dump() the two values you're comparing to see what those values are.  If it's not your error message, then the problem is the user / password you're using in your connection to the database, and not your query.

Comment: @devlincarnate Yes it's my alert message that pops up, I will perform a var_dump() and see what happens!

Comment: If you copy and pasted the same code completely, there is a good chance you overlooked to change the database name, database password, etc. Are you sure you are making a connection to the database? Have you tested?

Comment: @Webeng Yes sorry for not including that in the post, but we've made a seperate connection function for the remote database, and we do get access to it (since we can correctly register users, not login though :().

Comment: Then why don't you try `echo`ing a "test" password from you database onto the browser to see what is being retrieved, and also see what would happen to that same password after applying the `hash` code to it.

Comment: I've my money on password column length too short. If it's anything less than 60, then there you go. You need to start over. and please, vampires can stay in their coffins on this one ;-) and make sure you started the session.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the following answer because this is what I feel is the solution to the problem.

Your password column's length is likely to be too short (less than 60) and you would need to do the following and in the order shown:

- Erase your present hashes
- ALTER your (password) column to be 60+
- Enter/create new hashes
- Login/try again

Do make sure that you have data to start with, **being a hash and not a plain text password** (and other relevant data to query the database), and that the column types are correct, including the length for the email column, or any other for that matter.

As per the manual on `password_hash()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Example hash (60 char. length):

> $2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a

**PASSWORD_DEFAULT** - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

**PASSWORD_BCRYPT** - Use the **CRYPT_BLOWFISH** algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or **FALSE** on failure.

If that still doesn't resolve it, then either your POST arrays have no values, or there was whitespace that was introduced somewhere.

- Your posted code was tested against an existing database and yielded TRUE.

---

**Check for errors also.**

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

---

**Footnotes:**

I don't see the need for `global $mysqli;`. That is mostly used when a custom function is introduced. If you are **not** using a custom function, it can safely be removed.

However, if you are using a custom function, you have failed to post it in your question.

The MySQL API connection is also unknown, so make sure you did establish a successful connection with the MySQLi_ API.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php